# Creating Subscription payments using PayPal SDK with .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, paypal, asp.net-mvc-5

I have found this code on the following website:

```
https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/recurring_payment_ec/dotnet?interactive=ON&env=sandbox
```

The code is as follows:

```
SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType ecDetails = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();
ecDetails.ReturnURL = "https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/recurring_payment_ec/dotnet?success=true";
ecDetails.CancelURL = "https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/recurring_payment_ec/dotnet?cancel=true";
ecDetails.PaymentDetails = paymentDetails;

BillingCodeType billingCodeType = (BillingCodeType)EnumUtils.GetValue("RecurringPayments", typeof(BillingCodeType));
BillingAgreementDetailsType baType = new BillingAgreementDetailsType(billingCodeType);
baType.BillingAgreementDescription = "recurringbilling";
ecDetails.BillingAgreementDetails.Add(baType);

SetExpressCheckoutRequestType request = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType();
request.Version = "104.0";
request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = ecDetails;

SetExpressCheckoutReq wrapper = new SetExpressCheckoutReq();
wrapper.SetExpressCheckoutRequest = request;
Dictionary<string, string> sdkConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
sdkConfig.Add("mode", "sandbox");
sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiUsername", "jb-us-seller_api1.paypal.com");
sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiPassword", "WX4WTU3S8MY44S7F");
sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiSignature", "AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A7yDhhsPUU2XhtMoZXsWHFxu-RWy");
PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = new  PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(sdkConfig); 
SetExpressCheckoutResponseType setECResponse = service.SetExpressCheckout(wrapper);
```

This first part of the code is responsible for creating a PayPal billing agreement on basis which is specified in the parameters of the code.

The call then at the end returns a string as following:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-4SD42613U5111594L
```

This takes the user to the paypal site to confirm the billing agreement and the user is then returned to my website.

Then to create a recurring payments profile associated with the billing agreement, which was created using the SetExpressCheckout call, make a CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API call with the token you got in SetExpressCheckout API response and the billingAgreementDescription used in SetExpressCheckout API request.

The code looks as following:

```
 CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType createRPProfileRequest = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType();
CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType createRPProfileRequestDetails = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType();
createRPProfileRequestDetails.Token = "EC-4SD42613U5111594L";
createRPProfileRequest.CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails = createRPProfileRequestDetails;

RecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsType profileDetails = new RecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsType("2016-010-31T00:00:00:000Z");
profileDetails.RecurringPaymentsProfileDetails = profileDetails;

int frequency = 10;
BasicAmountType paymentAmount = new BasicAmountType((CurrencyCodeType)EnumUtils.GetValue("USD", typeof(CurrencyCodeType)), "1.0");
BillingPeriodType period = (BillingPeriodType)EnumUtils.GetValue("Day", typeof(BillingPeriodType));
BillingPeriodDetailsType paymentPeriod = new BillingPeriodDetailsType(period, frequency, paymentAmount);

ScheduleDetailsType scheduleDetails = new ScheduleDetailsType();
scheduleDetails.Description = "recurringbilling";
scheduleDetails.PaymentPeriod = paymentPeriod;
profileDetails.ScheduleDetails = scheduleDetails;

CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq createRPProfileReq = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq();
createRPProfileReq.CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest = createRPProfileRequest;

Dictionary<string, string> sdkConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
sdkConfig.Add("mode", "sandbox");
sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiUsername", "jb-us-seller_api1.paypal.com");
sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiPassword", "WX4WTU3S8MY44S7F");
sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiSignature", "AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A7yDhhsPUU2XhtMoZXsWHFxu-RWy");
PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = new  PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(sdkConfig); 
CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseType createRPProfileResponse = service.CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile(createRPProfileReq);
```

A response will be returned containing PROFILEID and ACK values:

```
PROFILEID=I-0H1CDRF2NEWB&PROFILESTATUS=ActiveProfile&TIMESTAMP=2016-10-31T15:56:13Z&CORRELATIONID=a5fcc91e86a24&ACK=Success&VERSION=104.0&BUILD=24616352
```

Once that is finished, I store hte ProfileID parameter into my DB so that I can handle the subscriptions for the future...

My question here is: how do I manage the subscriptions on monthly/yearly basis (depending how the user decides that he will pay monthly or yearly)?

There are couple of scenarios here that I'm thinking of:

1. What if user cancels the billing agreement via paypal ? Should I then check the subscription status upon every user login ?
2. Billing on the PayPal's side is probably done automatically , or do I have to create a payment request somehow every 1 month / 1 year in order to charge the user for using premium services on my website???

This is all still very confusing for me since I'm encountering this sort of problem for the first time since I started to do coding...

Can someone help me out?